# i m getting json parser error in alert box with error code 555

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

this is my code for parsing the data, I am able to hit the url but getting parse error. I used here `getElementById()` to accept the value from user and convert it to json dynamically but it's not a valid json. So tell me the way to accept data from user and convert it to json and send it to server.

```
var objectData = {
    "firstName" : document.getElementById('firstName').value,
    "lastName" : document.getElementById('lastName').value,
    "emailAddress": document.getElementById('emailAddress').value ,
    "password" : document.getElementById('password').value,
    "phoneNumber" : document.getElementById('phoneNumber').value 
}
var objectDataString = JSON.stringify(objectData);
alert(objectDataString);
var url = "http://ec2-54-201-121-123.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/refer247/registration";
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        alert('connected..');
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

and this is the data I'm sending to server.. but empty json is sending to server.

```
data: {
    o: objectDataString
},
```

anyone can solve this problem? not getting where I'm wrong..?

Comment: You're not sending anything to the server. There's no argument to `xmlhttp.send`.

Comment: okk..but after including  still getting json parser error..?

Comment: Show how you're including it.

Comment: xmlhttp.send(objectDataString); in alert box getting json parser erro and from server getting this error POST http://ec2-54-201-121-123.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/refer247/registration 500 (Internal Server Error)  and the data is going in text /html

Comment: What does the code on the server look like?

Comment: What is the result of alert(objectDataString); ?

Comment: the server should display that data in json format.i used php script for that..

Comment: it gives data in json format in alert box but getting error still..that json parser failed..

Comment: Please update your **question and its code** to have it up to date instead of posting hunks into as a comment.

Comment: it gives data in json format like { "name":"abc","email" :"sdsdd@gmail.com"}

Comment: my question is same.i am getting right json in alert but when i checked in json validator its not a valid json.